# External Jars in VS code

Tags: java, jar, visual-studio-code

I have a program written in java using Eclipse. For some reason that I won't write here, I decided to move to VS Code. If I run my code in debug mode, all works, but, when I want to export as jar file some errors comes out. 
Some information:
 - The program is composed by several classes.
 - I use 3 external jars included via Eclipse.
 - If I run the code with the extension 'Java extension pack - microsoft' all works. Compiling via terminal with 
`javac MyApp.java`
it doesn't compile. (It doesn't find some classes belonging to external jars)
 - If I use 
`jar -cvfm MyApp.jar manifest.txt *.class`
where *.class are created by compiling via 'Java extension pack' the error is 'Unable to find or load the main class'
 - I'm using a MacBook Pro and the last version of VS Code

What do I do wrong? Which more information you need to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your project has app package. Under that a App.java class resides which has the main method. Now after building the class files let's assume the class file folder structure is

```
bin
   |app
       |App.class
```

Now go to the bin folder and copy the manifest.txt file in bin folder. manifest.txt file must contain Main-Class . here app.App is the name of the Main-Class.

```
 Main-Class: app.App
```

**Note** manifest.txt file must be ended with a new line or carriage return . After `Main-Class: app.App` put a new line at least.Now run this command from the **bin** folder

```
jar cfmv App.jar manifest.txt app/
```

then test the Jar with

```
java -jar App.jar
```